# PowerShell: Parse Non-delimited Array Into Columns

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse an un-structured array into columns when that array is missing delimiters. The way the array looks from a data operation after inputted into a text file is below:

```
DC1
49600 Reachable 
49601 Reachable 
49602 Reachable 
49603 Reachable 
49604 Reachable 
49605 Reachable 
49606 Reachable 
49607 Reachable 
DC2
49600 Reachable 
49601 Reachable 
49602 Reachable 
49603 Reachable 
49604 Reachable 
49605 Reachable 
49606 Reachable 
49607 Reachable
```

The data array inside the an HTML email looks like this:
Screenshot #1:

[image: Screenshot #1]
I need it to be two columns instead, like this: 
Screenshot #2:

[image: Screenshot #2]

What I've tried is a few things, first, assigning the array to a variable, $Result.  I then out-file that to a text file and then email $Result in the body of an HTML email.  What winds up happening is the email body looks like the blob of text in Screenshot #1.  I then tried various "join" statements in various combinations to even worse results.  After banging my head for several hours, I've decided to post here.

EDIT:  Changed Subject line of question and the parts of the question where I mentioned strings - we are talking about arrays here, not strings. (Thanks Santiago)

Comment: Spaces or tabs can be delimiters as well. I'd expect you simply have to split your sample data into two sets and use `ConvertFrom-Csv` with the delimiter "\s". Anyway you should share the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is awfully complicated but should get you what you need. As you can see, it should work with multiple `DCxx`.

**Note:** The Here-String `@'...'@` is there just as an example to test the code, if this is read from a file, be sure to use the `-Raw` switch of `Get-Content`.

```
$result = [ordered]@{}

@'
DC1
49600 Reachable 
49601 Reachable 
DC2
49602 Reachable 
49603 Reachable 
49604 Reachable 
49605 Reachable 
49606 Reachable 
49607 Reachable 
DC3
49600 Reachable 
49601 Reachable 
49602 Reachable 
DC4 
49603 Reachable
49604 Reachable 
49605 Reachable 
49606 Reachable 
49607 Reachable
'@ -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
    
    $parse = ($_ -split '\r?\n' -ne '').ForEach('Trim')
    $header = $parse[0]
    $data = $parse[1..($parse.Count - 1)]
    $result.Add($header, $data)

}

$maxIter = $result.Keys.ForEach({$result[$_].Count}) | Measure-Object -Maximum

$toHTML = for($i = 0; $i -lt $maxIter.Maximum; $i++)
{
    $out = [ordered]@{}

    foreach($key in $result.Keys)
    {
        $out.Add($key, $result[$key][$i])
    }

    [pscustomobject]$out
}

$style = @'
<style>
* {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 10px;
}

th {
  background-color: #708090;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  text-align: left
}

td {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
</style>
'@

$toHTML | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $style | Out-File ./test.html
Invoke-Item ./test.html
```

[image: exampleOutput]

Comment: If I change the first line of yours to: *$report = [ordered]@{}* and remove the Here-String@'...'@, leaving everything else intact against my data set, results in a blank HTML file along with an error:  *Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2".*   Thank you for the effort you already put into this, Santiago.

Comment: Reason why I changed $Result to $Report:  Since I already had $Result defined previously, my thinking was to assign the data set to a new variable, and do the post-processing against that new variable to get to the nice columnar report you demonstrated.

Comment: @T-Heron did you change all instances of `$result` for `$report` on the code? Reading the file put together with the code (after removing the here-string) should be `(Get-Content path/to/file -Raw) -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne '' | ForEach-.....`

Comment: My $result is a string of data, which I'm now trying to use your code against to change it into a columnar report ($result is not actually read from a txt file, it's read from memory; I'm as of now doing away with reading from a txt file).  Therefore, since I have a $result, I only need to work against that. So, I changed only your top line from *$result = [ordered]@{}* to *$report = [ordered]@{}* and changed nothing else, except for removal of the example data in between the @'...'@ (and the surrounding @ from both sides of the example data of course).

Comment: For better context, I get $result like this, which gives me that big string of data to work against, then I'm trying to run your code:                                              *$Result = Foreach($DC in $DCList){
Write-output $DC;
(Test-RPC -ComputerName $DC);
}*

Comment: @T-Heron Your `$result` is not a string of data, it's an array. I coded this based on the fact the information was read from a file. Not going to change the code any further.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll re-visit outputting the *array* back into a file (what I was wrongly referring to as "string of data"), and then read from that using your code, to output into the columnar report.  Will re-visit that with fresh eyes in the morning.

Comment: @T-Heron you can try `($result | Out-String) -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne ''....` but it would have been by far easier to understand (and this should've been pointed out in the question) how were you getting that data because creating an `object[]` out of `Test-RPC` would've been a lot easier than parsing a (what I supposed was) text file. I even modified the original `Test-RPC` function to get a proper `object[]` out of it: https://github.com/santysq/Test-DCPorts/blob/main/Dependencies/Test-RPC.ps1

Comment: I'm working with your original answer - reading the file put together with the code (after removing the here-string) is now *(Get-Content path/to/file -Raw) -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne '' | ForEach-.....*  My question is what happens to your very first line of code *$result = [ordered]@{}*, does it go before or go after *(Get-Content path/to/file -Raw)*

Comment: @T-Heron it should go at the top of the script since it's being used on many lines of the script. If you modify the var name you should replace all instances of that var i.e.: `$result.Add($header, $data)`

Comment: The basic problem I had - was I was trying to combine my original script which pushed out the raw data - and then bolt on yours within the *same* script.  While that would certainly be possible to do based at your skill level - its not at mine yet.  By keeping my original script un-changed, and then running your code right behind it in a second script, it all works perfectly - shows me exactly what I need. As you had said - *Reading the file put together with the code (after removing the here-string) should be (Get-Content path/to/file -Raw) -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne ''*.

Comment: @T-Heron glad to hear it worked, I have a feeling that `$Result = Foreach($DC in $DCList){ Write-output $DC; (Test-RP...}` => `($result | Out-String) -split '\b(?=DC\d+)\b' -ne...`  should work too. But, the best approach you could take is to get a proper object that can be piped to `ConvertTo-HTML`. If you inspect the variable => `$toHTML | Out-GridView` after running the script you should see what I mean. That was the main idea behind my code, to parse that output you had into that. If you're not sure how to do that with the output from `Test-RPC` you could ask a new question.

Comment: Ah yes - doing that straight from the output of Test-TRPC would be a great challenge - the benefit being it would put everything nicely into one script.  That is a challenge for another day - and another question.   If and/or when I ever get around to doing that, I'll @notification you, just in case you may be interested in the future....